Unable to make Spring boot work with AttributeConverter
My application using Spring Boot 3.3.2 connects to multiple instances of the same DB structure, as each DB is owned by different clients. Said databases have names in Spanish, but our application is developed completely in English. I tried to create a AttributeConverter so I can transform one of the fields, that represents a status as ACTIVE or INACTIVE instead of ACTIVO and INACTIVO.
My converter looks like this:
import com.arkdia.seus.service.master.db.multi.enums.StatusEnum;
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import jakarta.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class StatusEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<StatusEnum, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(StatusEnum attribute) {
        return switch (attribute) {
            case ACTIVE -> "ACTIVO";
            case INACTIVE -> "INACTIVO";
        };
    }

    @Override
    public StatusEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return switch (dbData) {
            case "ACTIVO" -> StatusEnum.ACTIVE;
            case "INACTIVO" -> StatusEnum.INACTIVE;
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown status: " + dbData);
        };
    }
}

Everything was working fine until I added that converter, that's when I started to get this error:
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:365)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAttributeConverter(java.lang.Class)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.1.11/spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.1.11/spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder: file:/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.1.11/spring-orm-6.1.11.jar
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration: file:/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.5.2.Final/hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder

These are my dependencies:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.arkdia.seus.service.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>seus-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-maps-routing</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
        <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Any idea of what the problem could be?
Edit 1:
Adding the dependency three
 --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
 
 --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.6.1:tree (default-cli) @ seus-master-service ---
 com.arkdia.seus.service.master:seus-master-service:jar:1.0.23
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.26:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.26:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.13.2:compile
 |  |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.13.2:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.11:compile
 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:jar:4.1.4:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:4.1.4:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:4.1.4:compile
 |     |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.3.1:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:4.1.4:compile
 |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.1.3:compile
 |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:jar:1.78:compile
 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:4.1.3:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:4.1.3:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:jar:5.3.1:compile
 |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5:jar:5.2.5:compile
 |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5-h2:jar:5.2.5:compile
 |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:2.0.3:compile
 |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.20:compile
 |  |  |  \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.2:compile
 |  |  |     \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.netflix.spectator:spectator-api:jar:1.7.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.13:compile
 |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
 |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
 |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
 |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:runtime
 |  |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
 |  |  |  |     +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
 |  |  |  |     \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:runtime
 |  |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.5.3:runtime
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
 |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.5.4:runtime
 |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.1:compile
 |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:jar:4.1.4:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:jar:4.1.4:compile
 |     |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.6.8:compile
 |     |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
 |     |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.5.1:compile
 |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |     \- com.stoyanr:evictor:jar:1.0.0:compile
 +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.5:provided
 |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.5:provided
 |     +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.3:runtime
 |     +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:2.0.2:provided
 |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:4.0.5:provided
 |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.1.2:provided
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:jar:2.23.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.23.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.23.1:compile
 |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.23.1:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.22.1:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:5.1.0:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.5.2.Final:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.3.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:6.0.6.Final:runtime
 |  |  +- io.smallrye:jandex:jar:3.1.2:runtime
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.7.0:compile
 |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.18:runtime
 |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.13.0:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:6.1.11:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.26:compile
 |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:8.0.1.Final:compile
 |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
 +- com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.3.0:runtime
 +- com.arkdia.seus.service.commons:seus-commons:jar:1.0.13:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
 |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.17.2:compile
 +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.34:compile
 +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:3.2.0:compile
 +- com.google.maps:google-maps-routing:jar:1.21.0:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.24.1:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.61.1:runtime
 |  +- com.google.api:api-common:jar:2.26.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:jar:1.10.4:compile
 |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
 |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.25.2:compile
 |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:2.34.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.maps.api.grpc:proto-google-maps-routing-v2:jar:1.21.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:32.1.3-jre:compile
 |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
 |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.42.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:2.8:compile
 |  +- com.google.api:gax:jar:2.43.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:1.23.0:compile
 |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.31.1:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:1.23.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:2.43.0:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-inprocess:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- com.google.android:annotations:jar:4.1.1.4:runtime
 |  +- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.23:runtime
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-util:jar:1.61.1:runtime
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-alts:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-grpclb:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk-uber:jar:2.5.2:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.61.1:compile
 |  +- io.perfmark:perfmark-api:jar:0.27.0:runtime
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-googleapis:jar:1.61.1:runtime
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-xds:jar:1.61.1:runtime
 |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-proto:jar:0.2.0:runtime
 |  +- io.grpc:grpc-services:jar:1.61.1:runtime
 |  +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.7:runtime
 |  +- com.google.api:gax-httpjson:jar:2.43.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.10.1:compile
 |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.44.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14:compile
 |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.16.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16:compile
 |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:jar:0.31.1:compile
 |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.44.1:compile
 |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.25.2:compile
 |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-common-protos:jar:2.34.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:1.29.0:compile
 |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-iam-v1:jar:1.29.0:compile
 |  \- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.6.8:compile
 +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:4.12.0:compile
 |  +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:3.6.0:compile
 |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio-jvm:jar:3.6.0:compile
 |  |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.9.24:compile
 |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.9.24:compile
 |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.9.24:compile
 |     |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
 |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.9.24:compile
 +- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:3.1.8:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:3.3.2:runtime
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.3.2:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.2:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.3.2:test
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.3.2:test
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.3.2:test
 |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
 |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.2:runtime
 |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.5.1:test
 |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.5.1:test
 |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.6:test
 |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.25.3:test
 |  +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.2.1:test
 |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
 |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.10.3:test
 |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.10.3:test
 |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.3.0:test
 |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.10.3:test
 |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
 |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.10.3:test
 |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.10.3:test
 |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.10.3:test
 |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.11.0:test
 |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.18:test
 |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
 |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.11.0:test
 |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.3:test
 |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.1.11:test
 |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
 \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:3.3.2:compile


Why are you using Converter instead of a function to convert?, And where are u using that Converter in your project?

It looks like a jar version mismatch to me. Do you use spring boot dependencies to get the correct versions of the different libraries?

Have you tried it without autoApply=true?

Add dependency tree to your question mvn dependency:tree

Is there a reason you are using the plain hibernate SessionFactory over the auto-configured JPA? Can  you add the configuration you are using (the java one to do the setup)?

The fact org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder occurs in your stacktrace is suspicious; Spring Boot 3 uses Hibernate 6, so there shouldn't be reference to some hibernate5 package in there, I think.

I am trying to use a Converter just because it seemed like a great way to reuse is, since there are many other tables with the same statuses. I did add  autoApply=true, without success.

Regarding the usage of SessionFactory, that's because I need to configure different sets of connections, the microservice has it's own database, but at the same time it connects to multiple instances of the same database, each database beonging to a different client. The original monolithic application wasn't designed to be multitenant, so the microservice it's there to kind of fix that, while a new multitenant version of the application is build.
